# Why does gcc accept "int a = 3i;" as a valid statement?

Tags: c, gcc

When I write the following C code, I find that (contrary to what I expected), gcc can accept this code and compile it successfully! I don't know why for it seems it is a wrong statement.

```c
int main() {
    int a = 1i;
    return 0;
}
```

I guess it may be accepting `1i` as a complex number. Then `int a = 1i` means `int a = 0+1i` and `1i` is not a valid integer so it only accepts the `0`.

```
int main() {
    int a = 1i*1i;
    printf("%d\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried the code above and found that it printa -1. Maybe my thought is correct. But this is the first time I find that the C compiler can do this work.  Is my guess correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your intuition is correct.  gcc allows for complex number constants as an extension.

From the [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/gcc/Complex.html#Complex):

> To write a constant with a complex data type, use the suffix `i` or
> `j` (either one; they are equivalent). For example, `2.5fi` has type
> `_Complex float` and `3i` has type `_Complex int`. Such a constant always has a pure imaginary value, but you can form any complex value you
> like by adding one to a real constant. This is a GNU extension; if you
> have an ISO C99 conforming C library (such as GNU libc), and want to
> construct complex constants of floating type, you should include
> <complex.h> and use the macros `I` or `_Complex_I` instead.

So `1i` is the complex number i.  Then when you assign it to `a`, the complex part is truncated and the real part is assigned (and if the real part is a floating point type, that would be converted to `int`).

This conversion is spelled out in section 6.3.1.7p2 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> When a value of complex type is converted to a real type, the
> imaginary part of the complex value is discarded and the value of the
> real part is converted according to the conversion rules for the
> corresponding real type.